# How to store BigDecimal like 13.50 in DB using JPA (EclipseLink)?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I want to store an amount of money, let's say 13.50 into the Database using JPA (EclipseLink).

I declare the field as

```
private BigDecimal amout;
```

with no further annotations. This field is created as [`NUMERIC`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/san1278452907724.html) in Sybase DB.

When I store a `BigDecimal.valueOf(13.50D)`, in the database I only get 13,00 inside the database field. There is 0.50 missing.

The column would also support 13.50, I could enter it manually.
What should I do to write 13.50 into the database field? Do I need to adjust the BigDecimal value or / and do I need to set any precision annotation to the column?

To make the question more clear, here are some code snippets.

This is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "DBA"."BUCH" (
    "PNR" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT AUTOINCREMENT,
    "AMOUNT" NUMERIC(38,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( "PNR" ASC )
) IN "system";
```

This is the entity

```
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "BUCH")
public class Buch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int pnr;

    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 4, scale = 2))
    private BigDecimal amount;

    public Buch() {
        // JPA
    }
}
```

This is a test for it

```
@Test
public void test()  {

    Buch b = new Buch();
    
    BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("13.50");
    b.setAmount(amount);
    assertThat(b.getAmount(), is(new BigDecimal("13.50")));

    EntityManager em = createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(b);
    em.flush();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    List<Buch> allBuch = BuchDAO.getInstance().findAll();
    assertThat(allBuch.size(), is(1));

    Buch buch = allBuch.get(0);

    assertThat(buch.getAmount(), is(new BigDecimal("13.50")));

}
```

This is the test result

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <13.50>
     got: <13,00>
```

Comment: In principle the code that you have put in seems to be fine, you could try initializing the value as BigDecimal.valueOf (12.50); only

if it doesn't work, put the piece of code where you initialize the entity (or where you convert it) as well as the method in which you persist the object.

Regards

Comment: By the way, code such as `BigDecimal.valueOf( 12.50D )` is the wrong way to use `BigDecimal`. Passing a `double` means you have introduced the [inaccuracy of a floating-point type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems), thwarting the purpose in using a `BigDecimal`. Pass a `String` instead: `BigDecimal.valueOf( "12.50D" )`

Comment: What is the exact type of the column, in some databases, just `NUMERIC` will have an implementation specific precision and scale **0** (though this might not be the case for Sybase), meaning it will only accept whole numbers. To accept, 12.50, the column would need to be - for example - `NUMERIC(9, 2)`. In any case, it would be helpful to have a [mre], include a database schema and your Java code.

Comment: Turn on logging, and check what is actually in the database to determine if it is an issue with the input or the reading back of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/san1278452907724.html) for `DECIMAL` (`NUMERIC` is the same as `DECIMAL` in Sybase)…

> A signed decimal number with precision total digits and with scale of the digits after the decimal point. The precision can equal 1 to 126, and the scale can equal 0 up to precision value.

So a scale of zero means effectively integers only, with a decimal fraction of zero.

> The defaults are scale = 38 and precision = 126.

The defaults are certainly enough for your data example.

> Results are calculated based on the actual data type of the column to ensure accuracy, but you can set the maximum scale of the result returned to the application using the MAX_CLIENT_NUMERIC_SCALE option.

So you should check for two things in our database:

- The precision and scale set on your column definition.
- The value of the `MAX_CLIENT_NUMERIC_SCALE` option.